# Probabilty and Permutations

Tags: probability, permutations, divisibility

> A nine digit number is formed using 1 to 9 without repetition, find the probability of forming a number such that the product of any of its five  consecutive digits is divisible by 3 or 5.

Now my approach for solving this problem was to first find out the cases where this would not be possible.

If the product of five consecutive digits is divisible by 3 or 5, then the digits  must have atleast a multiple of 3 i.e. 3,6 or 9 or 5 as one of the 5 digits. The only case where this would not be possible would be when the special digits {3,6,9,5} are all huddled at one end of the number taking 4 of the 9 available spaces.

Now we have **4!=24** ways of arranging the four special digits and **5!=120** ways of arranging the remaining digits. Since the special digits can be huddled either at the end or at the start of the number, there would be **twice** the numbers not satisfying the condition specified in the question.

That results in **2.4!.5!=5760** rebellious numbers.

Since the total possible 9 digit numbers will be **9!=362880**, that leaves us with **362880-5760=357120** favourable outcomes. Therefore the required probability should be **357120/362880=0.984**

However that's not the answer, the answer specified is **0.96**

Can anybody please tell me where I went wrong?
(Pardon my formatting skills :)

Comment: They could be like $35*****69$, or any other way to distribute them in the beginning or in the end. So your $2$ should actually be...?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the numbers could be "huddled" in the middle as well, not only at the ends (for a total of 5 positions), so your probability should read:

$$1-\frac{5\cdot 4!\cdot 5!}{9!}$$

Comment: That was a very naive mistake of mine.